# Правильный import/export React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, create-react-app

Подскажите как правильно експортировать и импортировать несколько const.

file const.js

```
 const activeTabs = {
    /*code*/
    }
    const myContent = {
    /*code*/
    }
    const textForTab = [
    /*code*/
    ]
    export default activeTabs,myContent;
```

и есть файл App.js

```
import activeTabs from './const';
import myContent from './const';
```

Выдает ошибки или работает но при этом пустые const

Answer (score 4):

[`export default`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) может быть **только** один.

При этом экспортируется результат вычисления выражения.

В данном случае `export default activeTabs,myContent;` можно рассматривать как `export default (activeTabs,myContent);` что соответствует `export default myContent;`

Соответственно при импорте

```
import activeTabs from './const';
import myContent from './const';
```

В обоих переменных будет ссылка на `myContent`.

Чтобы экспортировать несколько частей можно в каждом из определений дописать `export`

```
export const activeTabs = {
    /*code*/
}
export const myContent = {
    /*code*/
}
export const textForTab = [
    /*code*/
]
```

Тогда импортировать их можно следующим образом:

```
import {activeTabs, myContent} from './const';
```

Либо в default возвращать объект, например:

```
export default {
    activeTabs,
    myContent,
    textForTab
};
```

При импорте:

```
import constants from './const';

// constants.activeTabs
```

Comment: а касетельно стилей? учитывая styled-compotents? Тоже так же?

Comment: @IlyaBurmaka, о каких стилях идет речь? В ответе примеры для импорта/экспорта который в js, в css есть свой собственный [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) но как я понял имелся ввиду не он?

Answer (score 2):

Основной вариант.Экспортируем все сразу

```
export { // без default
    textForTab,
    myContent,
    activeTabs
}
//потом импортируем
import {textForTab, myContent, activeTabs } from './const';
```

Также можно так писать

```
export  const activeTabs = {
    /*code*/
}
export  const myContent = {
    /*code*/
}
export  const textForTab = [
    /*code*/
]
//Можете  тут тоже импортировать точно также как наверху
```

Comment: Спасибо, а импорт?
`import activeTabs from './const';`

Comment: @IlyaBurmaka добавил